# Angular2 Trigger form.valueChanges manually

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I'm subscribing to my form changes with:

`this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(formData => { // Data is saved here. });`

When I click a button in my form it changes one of the input values. Somehow the valueChanges subscribe is not being triggered. Can I do this manually?

Comment: When you change the input value, does form value change? Did you check it?

Comment: Could you post some code demonstrating your button and how it drives the value change?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe you need to map the valuechanges before subscribing like:

```
 this.physicalForm.valueChanges
       .map((value) => {
          return value;
       })
       .subscribe((value) => {
         this.selectedPhysical.activityLevel = this.physicalForm.value.activityLevel;
       });
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense. You just pass a value 1:1.